# Converting a triangle to Barycentric Coordinates

Tags: coordinate-systems

Given the triangle T = (P1, P2, P3) with P1 = (-2, -1, 1), P2 = (2, 1,-1), and P3 = (3, 0, -4) and with texture (s, t) coordinates at the vertices defined as (0.25, 1.0), (0.8, 0.8), and (0.6, 1.0) respectively

Compute the texture coordinate  (s) for P with x and y coordinates = (0.5, 0.5). Use the standard  barycentric coordinate formula with beta = 5/6.

The main thing that i'm confused about is how to convert to barycentric coordinates. Any help?